# Regex for Positive numbers and -1 Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to look for it, but couldn't find any ref ,
I'm looking for a regex that will accept all positive integers include -1 (only - no other negative numbers) .

My regex is now /^\d+$/
But this is only for the part of all positive integers .

What should i add to that regex to work out ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: what about 0? is that counted?

Comment: Would `/^(-1|\d+)$/` do what you need?

Comment: 0 should be accepted also .

Comment: Yeah that works !! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `/^(-1|\d+)$/`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/dG3xS3/1

Comment: Glad that I could help :)